# How to parse a single TFrecord file

Tags: tensorflow, file-format

To read tfrecords:

```
reader = tf.TFRecordReader()
_, serialized_example = reader.read(filename_queue)
features = tf.parse_single_example(...)
```

TFRecordReader reads examples from a file queue.
But **how to read a single example from a particular file synchronically**(without a queue). like

```
file_buf = tf.read_file(filename)
serialized_example = get_train_example(file_buf)
features = tf.parse_single_example(...)
```

how to implement the **get_train_example** function

Comment: Could you explain a bit more about the problem you're trying to solve with this? That might help suggest a good approach.

Comment: what I want is just one way to parse a TFrecord file directly. TFRecordReader works on a file queue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure if this exactly what you're looking for, but you can do it this way without a queue:

```
tf_record = "path/to/my.tfrecord"
e = tf.python_io.tf_record_iterator(tf_record).next()
single_example = tf.parse_single_example(e, features=features)
```

Comment: very useful for debugging.

Comment: This gives AttributeError: 'generator' object has no attribute 'next'

Comment: If you are using python 3.x you need to use `next(...)` instead.

Answer (score 1):

used this one

```
for example in tf.python_io.tf_record_iterator("path_to_your_file"):
    result = tf.train.Example.FromString(example)
print(result)
```

found it [here](https://www.damienpontifex.com/2017/12/02/inspecting-tfrecord-files-and-debugging-tensorflow-data-input/)